# Setting Layout params programmatically recyclerview's item

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am using `RecyclerView` in which I have a `RelativeLayout`. In that `RelativeLayout`, I have a 2 `TextView`. If the first `TextView` has some value which decides if the second `TextView` should be aligned to right or left.

I have set the `LayoutParams` in `RecyclerView` Adapter using the below code:

```
if (listItem.getmLikeCount() > 0) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams feedCommentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    feedCommentParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    listItemHolder.mCommentCount.setLayoutParams(feedCommentParams);
} else {
    listItemHolder.mLikeCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams feedCommentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    feedCommentParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
    listItemHolder.mCommentCount.setLayoutParams(feedCommentParams);
}
```

But the items are getting recycled i.e. if any of the `RecyclerView` items is not having any `count` then all other items are also aligned to the left.

I want to show the comment count to Right if like `count > 0` else show comment count to left.

Comment: If requirement is this little one then why you are trying to do it in code, use android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" in xml it will manage from xml only

Comment: Or be lazy and just create two different 'TextViews' with separate alignment.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be easily solved with two `TextView` aligned separately. So that based on comments count you could set their visibility to `GONE` or `VISIBLE`.

Anyway, in your case you might consider calling the `requestLayout` inside the if and else statement like this.

```
if (listItem.getmLikeCount() > 0) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams feedCommentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    feedCommentParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    listItemHolder.mCommentCount.setLayoutParams(feedCommentParams);

    // Call requestLayout here 

} else {
    listItemHolder.mLikeCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams feedCommentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    feedCommentParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
    listItemHolder.mCommentCount.setLayoutParams(feedCommentParams);

    // Call requestLayout here for the else part. 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please tell me what should I write in place of // Call requestLayout here for the else part in the above code.